# Can lua_status detect if a function yields after being called using lua_call?

Tags: c++, lua

this is my first question on this *forum* so please excuse me if I don't do this correct.
I am currently working on a little project in C++ which uses the Lua API and I am trying to detect yielding without using **lua_resume** and **lua_pcall**. The reason for not using these is just simply because I can't use them for this project.
This is a small representation of the code I have to run the delay function I registered.

```cpp
void DoSleep(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "custom_delay"); // Custom function
    lua_pushnumber(L, 2); // Seconds
    lua_call(L, 1, 0); // 1 arg, no returns

    // Can I see if it yields using lua_status?
}
```

Basically, like you can see in my code my question is the following; **Will I get a return from lua_resume if lua_call yields?**

Answer (score 1):

Code ran by `lua_call` **can't** yield. For yielding to work, you'd have to use `lua_callk` instead. Once you do that, it'll be obvious whether the Lua code yielded: Just check the `status` parameter to your `k` function. Example:

```
static void DoSleep_k(lua_State* L, int status, lua_KContext ctx)
{
    if(status == LUA_YIELD) {
        // It yielded
    } else {
        // It didn't yield
    }
}

void DoSleep(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "custom_delay"); // Custom function
    lua_pushnumber(L, 2); // Seconds
    lua_KContext ctx = 0; // If you have any C local variables you care about, squeeze them in here somehow. Otherwise, just leave it 0.
    lua_callk(L, 1, 0, ctx, DoSleep_k); // 1 arg, no returns
    DoSleep_k(L, LUA_OK, ctx);
    // Don't put any more code here! Anything you want to happen after you call back into Lua, do in DoSleep_k above instead.
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
I looked into lua_callk and it seems to be using luaD_call. Does luaD_call support yielding, sir?

Comment: @Kiko Yes, but it's also an internal implementation detail of Lua. What do you plan to do with that knowledge?

Comment: I'm creating metatable exploit for Lua games that can execute custom lua code. It's hard checking for yielding since lua_pcall is not an option while doing this.